# New window from servlet method doGet()

Tags: servlets

Im invoking doGet method "download" servlet in myproject. what i want is,one new window should come out with static content? any idea my googling capacity have no luck

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
        out.println("static content");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from the servlet. That needs to be done by whatever sends the client to the servlet. It can be done with a Javascript popup window obviously, where the url is set to the servlet url, but there are two other options also:

Adding target='_blank' to a link:

```
<a href="serlvet" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Adding target='_blank' to a form:

```
<form action="serlvet" method="get" target="_blank">
```